# An additional assumption to the inverse function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, inverse-function

The theorem is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

And here is the question:

[image]

Could anyone give me a hint on how to prove the required in the question please?

Comment: In order to show that the inverse is also a $ \mathcal{C}^R $ mapping you can use Cramer's rule to explicitly calculate the partial derivatives of the inverse function. This gives you a relation between the partial derivatives of h and the partial derivatives of $h^{-1}$.

Comment: Could you provide more details please?@C.Grant

Comment: My impression is that, following C. Grant's advice, you should ignore everything other than part (e) of the theorem.

Comment: @CJD could you provide more details please :)

Comment: @hopefully Say the Jacobian of $f$ is $\left( \begin{array}{cc} a(x) & b(x) \\ c(x) & d(x) \end{array} \right)$, and we know that its determinant is non-zero in $B$ (because an inverse exists) and we know the component functions have continuous partial derivatives to I guess $k-1$ order.  For example, the top left entry of the inverse matrix would be $d(x)/(a(x)d(x) - b(x)c(x))$.

Comment: @hopefully. If you want to show that the inverse function is $\mathcal{C}^r$ it suffices to show that the partial derivatives are $\mathcal{C}^{r-1}$.   In order to do this use part (e) of the statement of the implicit function theorem. You know that $Dh(v)=(DF(h(v)))^{-1}$ so we may use Cramer's rule to solve for the ij-th entry of $Dh(v)$. In particular the ij-th entry is given by $$\frac{\det((DF(h(v))_{ij)}{\det(DF(h(v))} $$ where $Df(h(v))_{ij}$ is the matrix obtained from$Df(h(v))$ by deleting the ith row and jth column. Lastly this entry will be $\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}$.

Comment: is the solution very large @C.Grant ?

Comment: Could you please write the solution @C.Grant, I failed to do it?

Comment: Could you please write the solution , I failed to do it? @CJD

Comment: $$\frac{\det((DF(h(v))_{ij)}{\det(DF(h(v))} $$ what is this @C.Grant

Comment: why you reduced the order of the partial derivatives by 1@C.Grant

Comment: How $$\frac{\det((DF(h(v))_{ij)}{\det(DF(h(v))} $$? ..... f capital or small?

Comment: @C.Grant what is the difference between applying Cramer`s rule in our problem and applying cramer`s rule for solving system of 3 linear equations as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtxVGMWXMSE  ..... in the video we remove the first column and put instead of it the constant terms in our system of equations to find the value of x ..... then repeat this step for y & z.

Comment: Cramer`s is used to solve $Ax = b$ what is the b in our case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more general form of Cramer's rule than the one used for solving system's of linear equations. See the section on inverting matrices here on Wikipedia for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix.

In this question in particular we have that $Dh(v)= (Df(h(v)))^{-1}$ by part (e) of the inverse function theorem. To show that the inverse function is also a $\mathcal{C}^{r}$ function we must show that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}$ of the function are $\mathcal{C}^{r-1}$ (as then the original function will be $\mathcal{C}^r$.)

Using the version of Cramer's rule above we have that the ij-th entry of $(Df(h(v)))^{-1}$ (and hence the partial derivative $\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}$) will be given by:

$$
((Df(h(v))^{-1})_{ij} = \frac{\det(A)}{\det(Df(v(h)))}
$$
Where $A$ is the matrix obtained from $Df(v(h))$ by co-factor expanding on the ij-th entry of the matrix.

This expression gives $\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$. In particular we see that the partial derivative of $h_i$ with respect to $x_j$ is a quotient of a sum and product of $\mathcal{C}^{r-1}$ functions and a no-where zero $\mathcal{C}^{r-1}$ function on the ball.

We conclude from this that the partial derivates of the inverse function are $\mathcal{C}^{r-1}$ and hence the inverse function is $\mathcal{C}^r$.

Comment: Does not the question asks for the proof of the existence only ...... is not their  a proof of the existence without calculation?

Comment: How is the original function is $C^k$ while the partial derivatives are $C^{k-1}$ could please give me an example?

Comment: How are you sure that there exist an open n-ball such that the inverse is $C^k$

Comment: I think we have to take the transpose of A.

Comment: Taking the transpose of A is equivalent to taking A as determinants are invariant under taking the transpose.

Comment: The set f(B) is open and thus there is an open ball contained in f(B) around any point f(b) for $ b \in B$. The argument given above shows that in any neighbourhood where the determinant of $Df(h(v))$ is non zero that the inverse function has partial derivatives that are $\mathcal{C}^{r-1}$.